# Updatepanel issue with client side "class" changing of a control inside repeater

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm having trouble with using UpdatePanel and changing the 'class' attribute of a control inside a repeater by javascript.

Here some code:

--on the aspx--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass(ctl) {
        if (ctl.className == "marked") {
            ctl.className = "unmarked";
        } else {
            ctl.className = "marked";
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- some html -->
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upp" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a id="aButton" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <!-- some other controls -->
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

--Codebehind--

```
protected void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        MyClass obj = (MyClass)e.Item.DataItem;

        ((HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("aButton")).Attributes.Add("class", "marked");

        //some other code....
    }
}

//method called after the bind on 'rpt1'
private void mymethod()
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rpt1.Items)
    {
        HtmlAnchor aButton = (HtmlAnchor)ri.FindControl("aButton");
        if (Must-be-unmarked)
            aButton.Attributes.Add("class", "unmarked");

        aButton.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "changeClass(this);");
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I click on an "aButton" the class is changed normally, but when I come in codebehind and get de 'class' of control to check if it's marked or unmarked,  I only get the controls marked in ItemDataBound of repeater, not the "aButton"s marked by me at execution time.

here is what I do to get the "aButton"s marked:

```
private void checkMarked()
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rpt1.Items)
    {
        if (((HtmlAnchor)ri.FindControl("aButton")).Attributes["class"] == "marked")
        {
            //do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change class property from client-side code, the server side will not know about it.

You'll need to add a hidden `<input>` with marked/unmakred so you can check the contents from the server on a post-back.

Another approach would be to sipmly have your javscript postback to the server directly when an item changes from marked/unmakred.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I really want to get the class but my problem was solved by using the HiddenField solution.